# Sound Blaster Audigy FX No sound

Tags: windows, drivers, gpu, sound-card, software-conflict

Hi I have a pci express sound blaster audigy fx card and a pci express ati radeon hd7970 graphics card.

When I install the official drivers from the creative website I get different results in the device manager. It says that the card is a SB Recon3d card, also a sound blaster audio controller. here is an image of the device managerin its current state.

[image: device manager]

I do have onboard sound which is disabled in the bios. But from my research I think it is the hdmi sound and audigy card not playing well together. I have also disabled the gpu card to no avail.

Now the confusing thing is , this was working for a short while and now its not!

If I do a test while all the speakers in the sound blaster control panel , I have to have the speakers at full and I can here it a little.

my sound card: Sound blaster Audigy Fx
my gpu: Asus HD7970DC2T3GD5

Can any one help me on some advanced debugging on this issue? Or even better a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the default audio device selected?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the default is the soundblaster audigy fx